# Is it possible to use x-goog-if-generation-match in google.cloud.storage python client?

Tags: python, google-cloud-storage

I'm using google.cloud.storage Python library to store files in Google Cloud Storage from my App Engine flexible application. I would like to x-goog-if-generation-match header to prevent overwriting newer versions, but can't find a way to pass it to the library.

Is it possible to utilise blob generation checking with google.cloud.storage Python library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of today, google cloud python client supports generation and metageneration in the API, including `Blob.upload_from_string`:

https://googleapis.dev/python/storage/latest/generation_metageneration.html#conditional-parameters

> Using if_generation_match
>
> Passing the if_generation_match parameter to a method which retrieves a blob resource (e.g., Blob.reload) or modifies the blob (e.g., Blob.update) makes the operation conditional on whether the blob’s current generation matches the given value.
> As a special case, passing 0 as the value for `if_generation_match` makes the operation succeed only if there are no live versions of the blob.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK the `x-goog-if-generation-match` header is only available in the [XML API](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/generations-preconditions#_XMLAPI).

The `google.cloud.storage` library doesn't allow generic, direct access to the request headers. In some cases access is supported, but via dedicated properties and I see none equivalent to `x-goog-if-generation-match` in [`google.cloud.storage.blob.Blob`](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/storage/blobs.html#google.cloud.storage.blob.Blob).

I do see methods for retrieving the object/blob's generation and meta-generations, though (but those aren't equivalent to `x-goog-if-generation-match`):

> **generation**
>
> Retrieve the generation for the object.
>
> See https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects
>
> Return type:  int or `NoneType` Returns:  The generation of the blob or
>   `None` if the blob’s resource has not been loaded from the server.

and

> **metageneration**
>
> Retrieve the metageneration for the object.
>
> See https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects
>
> Return type:  int or `NoneType` Returns:  The metageneration of the blob
>   or `None` if the blob’s resource has not been loaded from the server.